# How to stop execution of quartz scheduler job in c#

Tags: c#, quartz.net

How to stop execution of quartz scheduler job in c#

I have tried below code. but it did not work. Please suggest other solutions.

```
IScheduler scheduler = await _factory.GetScheduler();
var executingJobs = await scheduler.GetCurrentlyExecutingJobs();

var jobKeys = await scheduler.GetJobKeys(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("group1"));

//loop through the jobs and interrupt them
foreach (JobKey jobKey in jobKeys)
{
 scheduler.Interrupt(jobKey);
}

// stop the scheduler
scheduler.Shutdown();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pause/resume jobs with Quartz.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314199/how-to-pause-resume-jobs-with-quartz-net)

Comment: @godot Actually no.
but can you answer this.. how to check current job is stopped or not ?

Comment: So you want to pause certain jobs, or all of them? or just get their statuses or what?

Comment: yeah.. I want to stop particular one job. but also want to verify once it is stopped